# Decrypt PHP mcrypt and md5 in Python

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

Hi i have this PHP decryption and encryption code for login passwords and i need to check it with python directly from Mysql, so i need to decrypt passwords in python can anyone help me with? Here is php code:

```
function encryptIt($value) {
        $encodeKey = 'MY FIXED KEY';
        $encoded = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($encodeKey), $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($encodeKey))));
        return($encoded);
    }

function decryptIt($value) {
        $decodeKey = 'MY FIXED KEY';
        $decoded = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($decodeKey), base64_decode($value), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($decodeKey))), "\0");
        return($decoded);
    }
```

first function take password as ($value) and return me encoded one, that will save to Database, and second function take encoded password as ($value) and return me normal password. **i need to code second function in python**

Comment: Well, what attempt have you made? What problems are you having with it?

Comment: You don't decrypt hashed passwords you compare them to other hashed strings.

Comment: md5 is a hash function, not an encryption function.

Comment: Thanks for comment, first function take password as ($value) and return me encoded one that will save to Database, and second function take encoded password as ($value) and return me normal password. i need to code **second function** in python

Comment: Take a look at [mcrypt](http://labix.org/python-mcrypt) lib, that may help you!